# Convert xhr ajax call to xdr for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have asp web page responsible of uploading file using ajax.

the html code of the form is:

```
<form method="post" action="ajax/firmwareUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform" name="uploadform">
    <div class="left">
    <span id="lang502009" title="502009">Firmware File</span>:
    <input name="download image file" id="uploadfilename" type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <div class="upload" id="uploadManual">
    <input type="submit" class="button button-blank" value="Upload"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the ajax code is :

```
$("#uploadform").submit(function(e) {
     $.ajax({
     url:  'ajax/firmwareUpload',
     type: 'POST',
     data: new FormData(this),
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
     success: function(data) {
     if (data.error) {
     $("body").load("subpage/upgradefail.asp");
     setTimeout(backToIndex, 5*1000);
     }
     else {
     var time = data.return;
     $("body").load("subpage/upgradewait.asp");
     setTimeout(backToIndex, time*1000);
     }
     },
     error: function(data) {
     alert("Operation could not be completed");
     }
     });
     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

This code works well as wanted for different browsers like firefox, chrome, safari, Opera. but I got problems with IE8 in the ajax response.
But the request works fine and can receive from the browser and send to the browser the response. But when IE8 receives the response it can't access to the success or error functions.
After a lot of searches I found in the internet that the problem is because IE8 have some problems with xhr communication. And the ajax code can be better with xdr.
My problem here is how I can convert my ajax code to xdr? 
The problem especially is with processData, enctypes attributes and "new new FormData(this)". and is there modification that should be done in the tag form attributes?

Comment: XDR won't help with this. It lets you do some things with CORS that weren't supported in ancient versions of XHR, but your problem is that IE8 doesn't support the File API.

Comment: IE 8 does not receive security updates any more. Microsoft don't support it. It is dangerous to let loose on the Internet. Systems using it should be upgraded to something modern. I would recommend not supporting it.

Comment: I don't think it's so dangerous. What I'm doing is not an application that will be executed in the internet. It's web pages for a router with asp and C. and that's a page to upgrade a new firmware for the router. and it has to be done with IE8

Comment: you might want to look into a pre-built solution that is backwards compatible. BlueImp File Upload has a lot of features but you will need to use your own upload handler in ASP. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: @Quentin do you have an idea how that can be fixed?

Comment: @KallelOmar — The fix is to upgrade the browser. I'm not inclined to explain how to hack around missing features in security hole ridden browsers so people can continue to use security hole ridden browsers.